# FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar not found in release build of Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have Firebase integrated into my Flutter project, for Storage. This works fine on my debug builds, but not in my release build.

The relevant lines from my pubspec.yaml:

```
  # Firebase core
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  # Firebase cloud storage
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.8
  # Google analytics
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
```

The error I see on startup of the release app is:

```
2020-04-16 13:19:38.765 25613-25613/? W/ComponentDiscovery: Class io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar is not an found.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
        at com.google.firebase.components.h.a(:78)
        at com.google.firebase.components.h.a(:71)
        at c.a.b.c.<init>(:468)
        at c.a.b.c.a(:354)
        at c.a.b.c.a(:321)
        at c.a.b.c.b(:305)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(:53)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FlutterFirebaseAppRegistrar
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.h.a(:78) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.h.a(:71) 
        at c.a.b.c.<init>(:468) 
        at c.a.b.c.a(:354) 
        at c.a.b.c.a(:321) 
        at c.a.b.c.b(:305) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(:53) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(:47) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?